# How to view .net application in chrome or firefox browser

Tags: vb.net

I wrote project using vb.net with devexpress forms  , my question is there way to view my applicatin in browser like java applet or oracle forms.

Comment: If its WinForms, no.  If Asp.net then point your browser at wherever its hosted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to run an executable file built for windows could run in a browser independently. JAVA is platform independent that's why we are able to run JAVA apps in browser, even we cannot run android apps directly into browser, we have to have complete android emulator device to run android apps. In the same way, we cannot run executable files directly into browser, because they are generated with respect to underline hardware platform